# How to call oracle stored procedure in spring using entity manager?

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, oracle11g, procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST  
(
Role IN VARCHAR2, 
     OUTPUT 
 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
 OPEN OUTPUT FOR   
Select PC.PRODUCT_NAME,P.PARTNER_NAME
............
.............
  WHERE PC.ROLE_NAME='POS_LEAD';
END TEST;
```

Calling above procedure In Spring using below code

```
StoredProcedureQuery findByYearProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("TEST");

StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = findByYearProcedure
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("Role", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("SYS_REFCURSOR", Object.class,ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
            .setParameter("Role", "admin");

System.out.println(storedProcedure.getResultList());
```

But I am getting an error.

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST'
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> ```

can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to duplicate your issue but I cannot, though I'm using Postgres instead of Oracle.  Just to be sure, can you do this instead:

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = findByYearProcedure
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Object.class,ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
            .setParameter("Role", "admin");
```

Thanks

Comment: Also perhaps it needs to be a void.class instead of Object.class as seen in https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/stored-procedure-with-ref-cursor.html